# COPY FROM remote desktop

Tags: json, crate

Is possible to upload a json file using the `COPY` from a remote desktop?

Command:

```
crash --host 192.100.1.15:4200 -c "COPY doc.test FROM '/test.json'"
```

The file: `{"id": 1, "name": "foo"}`

Error:

> SQLActionException[SQLParseException: Column reference "test.json" has too many parts. A column must not have a schema or a table here.]

Second option:

```
crash --host 192.100.1.15:4200 -c "COPY doc.test FROM 'file:///test.json'"
```

> COPY OK, 0 rows affected  (0.001 sec)

Answer (score 1):

The files have to reside on the server-nodes in order to import them using COPY FROM. See [COPY FROM reference docs](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/reference/copy_from.html#description)

But there is a tool called cr8 which can be used to insert records from a JSON file: See [cr8 insert-json](https://github.com/mfussenegger/cr8#insert-json)